# How to change text of element when on mobile device Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My Question is How would I change the text of a HTML `<p>` tag when I am on a mobile device like android or iphone?

Here is my current code `p` tag:

```
<p>You are on a desktop good</p>
```

This is the `<p>` tag I want to appear on Desktop, Tablet and Laptop.

How can I make it so that it says the following on mobile device like android or iphone in Straight Up Javascript no bootstrap just JavaScript?

```
<p>Please Use a Desktop to view</p>
```

Please Help

Thank You For All answers

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: no i am not using bootstrap

Comment: css classes + media queries?

Comment: What have you tried? Use media queries and show one div at a certain breakpoint and hide the other.

Comment: Than you need to use a media query in your CSS file. Do you know what a media query is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

gives a id or specific class to your <p> tag and include the JS after the dom loaded

```
<p id="changeMe">Services</p>
<script>
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobile/)) {
document.getElementById('changeMe').innerHTML = 'Services Are everywhere';
}
</script>
```

Or use css Media Queries to show and hide Paragraphs

```
<p class="desktop"> Services</p>
<p class="mobile"> Services Are everywhere </p>

CSS:

p.mobile { display: none }
@media (max-width: 640px) {
    p.mobile { display: block }
    p.desktop { display: none }
}
```

Comment: care with media queries, iPhone 6 Plus viewport landscape width is 736px. Use JS for mobile detection.

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS media queries, and use elements to show or hide the element based on the screen width.

For example:

```
p.mobile {
    display: none;
}
p.desktop {
    display: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    p.mobile {
        display: auto;
    }
    p.desktop {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Using a `desktop` and `mobile` class on everything that should be on desktop or mobile (exclusive) is important, so that this style will work on all of those elements that you want to change.

Comment: or `<p class="all">Services<span class="mobile"> Are everywhere</span></p>`

Comment: with some media queries.

Comment: but what if i want to change it to something total diffrent

Comment: @JackSmith What do you mean?

Comment: @0x860111 But this solution works without adding extra elements and/or classes into the DOM...

Comment: @Jonathan like if the orginal content is Hello and i want to change it to 'Hi'

Comment: @JackSmith Oh that wasn't clear. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: @JackSmith No problem!

Comment: Yes, it works. But there is some problems. Semantics - content attribute is not flexible and not edit-friendly. One class can be reusable. If you change the css, user will load new css file (cache will not help).